# Android Tablet Lyaout

Tags: android, layout, tablet

I noticed that my app does not appear in GooglePlay for the Tablet. I created different layouts and inserted supports screens in the Manifest. What is missing? I have studied the documentation but do not understand what is missing. Thank you for your help.
In the Manifest

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

And I created the Folders with Layouts:

```
layout-sw600dp
layout-sw720dp
layout-large
layout-xlarge
layout-xxlarge
```

and the various Drawable folders:

```
drawable
drawable-hdpi
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be various things.
You need to set the right minimum and target sdk versions, provide screenshots of the tablet layout of your app and support all screen-sizes. Only creating folders isn't enough, you actually need to provide the right drawables there, too.

To see what is missing, look into you developer console.

> If you want to be sure your app is included in the “Designed for tablets” view, go to the Developer Console to check your tablet optimization tips. If you see any issues listed there, you’ll need to address them in your app and upload a new binary for distribution. If there are no issues listed, your app is eligible to be included in the “Designed for tablets" view in the top lists.

Source: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/10/more-visibility-for-tablet-apps-in.html

Comment: In my developer console I have this message:`In your layout, you should use the available space on the tablet 10 "`why does this tell me?I have inserted the Screenshots etc..

Comment: Do you have a link to your app in the play store, so that we could check it out?